# QGIS OpenStreetMap plugin: download failed. Server replied: bad request

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, error

I am trying to download Open Street Map data using the OpenStreetMap plugin in QGIS, and getting the following err:

[image: Server replied: bad request]

I'm kind of new on geoprocessing, so I have no clue what is going on here.

Comment: The plugin is still very buggy. I recommend to download an area outside QGIS and load it via the plugin ...

Comment: Try entering the bounding box in lat/lon manually. The coordinate values in the screenshot look very fishy.

Comment: Yep, it's still a bug if you don't use WGS84 projection in QGIS :-(

Comment: How could I convert from EPSG 3857 to lat/lon, so I could enter the bounding box mannualy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Google Streets map background from the openlayers plugin, the **project** CRS should be set to EPSG:3857 and `On-the-fly-reprojection` **enabled**.

With that setting, the Openstreemap plugin is able to convert the current map canvas extent to WGS84 latlong as needed for the Opverpass API.

See this ticket for further development on the matter: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11267

Comment: Settings: Google Streets layer -> EPSG:3857
Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation -> Enabled

But still getting the very same error.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Are you using the latest QGIS version 2.6? Does the extent change when you select "From layer" and back to "From map canvas?"

Comment: My version was 2.0.1. I updated to 2.6.0 and as for now everything is working OK; I was able to download the open street data using open street as background. Thank you

Comment: QGIS 2.0.1 was the very first version of the new Openstreetmap plugin, with some bugs that have been fixed in the meantime. Glad it works for you now.